# Inline asm in iOS error

Tags: ios, inline-assembly

int x;
    __asm __volatile("movl  %0,  %%sp":"=r"(x)::"%sp");
I want to store sp to x.
The error:

```
error: unexpected token in operand
    __asm __volatile("movl  %0,  %%sp":"=r"(x)::"%sp");
                     ^
:1:13: note: instantiated into assembly here
        movl  r0,  %sp
                   ^
1 warning and 1 error generated.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found my solution:

```
asm volatile("mov %0, sp \n\t":"=r"(x));
```

Comment: When read the document, it said that % is used to indicate a register. However, it is not true.

Comment: In gcc inline assembly, `%` indicates an _operand_. On x86, where the default AT&T assembly syntax uses `%` as prefix for a register, one sometimes has to write `%%` with gcc's inline asm, i.e. like `mov %%eax, %0` to copy the `EAX` reg into the first output operand. The assembly syntax on ARM requires no `%` to indicate registers, instead, register names are reserved keywords (you can't have a label named `sp`, for example). Still, as indicated in my post the variant of code you've given is ARM-only, while _this specific_ thing (reading `sp`) can be written CPU-independent. See my answer.

Answer (score 2):

What works for this specific case is:

```
register void* sp __asm__("sp");
__asm__("" : "+r"(sp) :: "memory");
```

It's even portable between ARM and x86 ...

Answer (score 0):

You are trying assemble x86 assembly for an ARM CPU.